# Bootbox.dialog and Autocomplete showing behind dialog

Tags: jquery, dialog, jquery-autocomplete, bootbox

I am having an issue with the jquery autocomplete showing behind the Bootbox.dialog
I show the bootbox.dialog in the schedulinging.js then in the  partial i attach my autocomplete to the control on the view. I have been reading not to use a Z-index with Jquery 1.10 but not sure how to get the autocomplete in the dom in the right position after the dialog.  I couldnt get the Z-index to work anyways.  Need some help getting this to work. Thanks!

```
bootbox.dialog({
                            message: result,
                            buttons: {
                                save: {
                                    label: "Save",
                                    className: "btn-primary btn-xs",
                                    callback: function () {
                                        var $form = $('#form');
                                        //Validating the form using unobtrusive validation.
                                        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($form);
                                        $("#form").validate();

                                        if ($("#form").valid()) {
                                            $.ajax({
                                                cache: false,




 $('#ScheduleItem_AdditionalDescription').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            var searchTerm = $('#ScheduleItem_AdditionalDescription').val();
            //Ajax call to retrieve the potiential auto complate results
            //based on the searchTemer that are passed in through the additional
            //description control.
            window.suppressBlockUI = true;
            $.ajax({
                url: "/ScheduleDetail/AutoCompleteAdditionalDesc",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: 'application/json, charset=utf-8',
                data: {
                    term: searchTerm
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    window.suppressBlockUI = false;
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.AdditionalDescription
                            //,
                            //value: item
                        };
                    }));
                }
            });
        }, minLength: 1,
        select: function (event, ui) {
        },
        open: function () {
            $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
        },
        close: function () {
            $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-all");
        }
    });
```

Comment: set z-index property to 99999 so that It will come forward

Comment: Had to add it in the right place. Added the z-index on the open of the autocomplete.   open: function () {   $(this).autocomplete('widget').css('z-index', 99999);

Comment: is it properly working now?

Comment: Yes it is workng now.

Comment: I think ,I posted the answer in Comments,sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set z-index property to 99999 so that It will come forward